# Total amount of rearrangements of letters

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

If we consider the letters 'OMORFADWRA' then we have the following: 
The subword 'OMORFA' is contained in $5!$ rearrangements. 
The subword 'DWRA' is contained in $7!$ rearrangements. Since at 'OMORFA' we have twice the letter O we get $\frac{7!}{2}$ rearrangements. We have calculated twice 'OMORFADWRA' and twice 'DWRAOMORFA'.

So the total amount of rearrangements that contain either the word 'OMORFA' or the word 'DWRA' or but not both of them is equal to $5!+\frac{7!}{2}-2-2$, or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. ${{{{{}}}}}$

Comment: Great! Thank you!! Do you meaybe have also an idea about my other question:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2898485/number-of-rearrangements-of-the-word ?