# Number of rearrangements of the word

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

We have the word 'EXETASTIKH'. I want to calculate the number of rearrangements so that at least one E is at its original position.

$$$$

For that do we consider the first E constant and calculate the number of rearrangements of the remaining letters plus the same considering the second E constant?

Would it be then $\frac{10!}{2!}+\frac{10!}{2!}$ ?

Comment: What are your thoughts about the question? Kindly consider explaining how did you reached the candidate answer which you propose ? :)

Comment: Mary, Won't there be cases when the second 'E' takes its original position when you are keeping first 'E' constant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As tdluong pointed out in a comment, apparently we both miscounted the letters. There are only $10$ letters in total, so only $9$ without the 'E's, so the answer is in fact

$$
\frac{9!}{2!}+\frac{9!}{2!}-\frac{8!}{2!}=342720\;.
$$

I'm leaving the original, incorrect answer here, too, to make sense of the comments:

---

That's almost right, except you're double-counting the arrangements with both 'E's in their original positions, so you need to subtract their number, for a total of

$$
\frac{10!}{2!}+\frac{10!}{2!}-\frac{9!}{2!}=3447360\;.
$$

Comment: Ah ok! Thank you very much!! :-)

Comment: Just a question. This is a 10 letter word. Isn't the answer: $2\times\frac{9!}{2!} - \frac{8!}{2!}$

Comment: @tdluong: I could have sworn I counted $10$ letters after the initial 'E' :-) [Confirmation bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias), I guess. Thanks for catching the error.

Comment: @MaryStar: Please note the change in the answer in response to tdluong's comment.